# Google cluod app engine flexible php deploying sql instance app error occurred while parsing app.yaml file, unexpected attribute cloud_sql_instances

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mysqli

I am working on an app-engine-flexible PHP project, and am planning to use mysqli to connect to database. Here is my `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web

## Uncomment for Cloud SQL
beta_settings:
cloud_sql_instances: "project-name:region:instance_name"
```

I could get the cloud SQL proxy to run on Windows, but I could not initialize my cloud SQL instance using TCP in my windows PC. I also could not connect using IP for local testing. I then decided their[sic] was no need for local testing.

I encountered another problem in trying to deploy the app using cloud SDK. It says:

> an error occurred while parsing file app.yaml. Unexpected attribute 'cloud_sql_instances' for object of type AppInfoExternal in app.yaml file line 9, column 22

Comment: Well good luck. lol

Answer (score 2):

Your `app.yaml` is misformatted, you need to indent the `cloud_sql_instances` element:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web

## Uncomment for Cloud SQL
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "project-name:region:instance_name"
```

And of course, you need to update the values for that element as well and follow any other instructions for making the connection to Cloud SQL.

Comment: I would just like to know why a tab caused this error for me as well.  seems like a design flaw.

Comment: That is just how YAML schemas work. It isn't consider a child element of beta_settings if it is at the same level.